# Regularity of zeros in a sparse matrix

Tags: random, sparse-matrices

I have a large matrix which is around 70% zeros. How can I test whether there is some statistical regularity to those zeros, as opposed to being randomly distributed?

Comment: You can make them data points on some grid. The simplest grid you can choose is probably a cartesian (row,column).